# Mainmenu layout not appears to be the desired layout

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new in Xamarin. I have problem fixing the Main_Menu.axml layout to my desired layout which is on the link below.How can I put a layout above and my gridview below? I need help in that.

Desired Layout is below

[image]

My current Mainmenu.axml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/sublayout_Toolbar" />
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/mainMenu_GridView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:listSelector="@null"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/light_blue" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My current layout as below

[image]

Comment: `Bug on Mainmenu layout` there is nothing about a bug in your question. Your question title doesn't match the question body.

Comment: already changed it

Comment: You could add a [Banner](https://github.com/youth5201314/banner) in your `LinearLayout` to implement this.